# multi level mapping (.map)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

i'm trying to map over an object but I struggle to manage to get the right results

my example array of objects

```
[
    {
        "round": 1,
        "points": 0,
        "colors": [
            "#c99e15",
            "#b9bbbd",
            "#7C0B2B",
            "#97CC04",
            "#7fffd4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "round": 2,
        "points": 0,
        "colors": [
            "#c99e15",
            "#b9bbbd",
            "#7C0B2B",
            "#476C9B",
            "#ADD9F4"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get a table where I get

**ROUND X // POINTS**

1. color 1
2. color 2
3. color 3
4. etc

**ROUND X+1 // POINTS**

1. color 1
2. color 2
3. color 3
4. etc

etc

my current code looks likes this, but this unfortunately keeps duplicating the results in "colors" values

```
<ul>
            {obj.map((round) => (
              <li key={round.round}>{round.round}
                <ul>
            {obj.map((outerElement) =>
            outerElement.colors.map((colors) => (
                <li key={colors} style={{ backgroundColor: colors }}>
                  {colors}
                </li>
              ))
            )}
          </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you `obj.map((outerElement) => ...)` inside the loop over the same object. you need to map over `round.colors`

```
<li key={round.round}>
  {round.round}
  <ul>
    {round.colors.map((color) => (
      <li key={color} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
        {color}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</li>
```